# Is there a (offical) way for a theme to deactivate itself and show a message in admin?

Tags: php, themes, wp-admin

I know that plugins can deactivate itself, but how about themes?

I work on a parent theme (Framework) and I don't want users to be able to activate it.

This is what I have so far. The problem is that there is a message coming up from wordpress that the theme is demaged when I do this this way. It shows the last theme there one time but then swiches again to the default theme because wordpress expect the theme I clicked activate for. I need to bypass this somehow. I want to show my own message instead. Any ideas?

Although I don't know if its right to set all to one value, isn't template supposed to be the parent themes name when there is one? Or does WP figure this out automatically?

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'switch_to_last_theme' );

function switch_to_last_theme( $old_theme ){

    echo "<br><br><h1>just for testing last theme: $old_theme</h1>";

    update_option('template', $old_theme);
    update_option('stylesheet', $old_theme);
    update_option('current_theme', $old_theme);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the `check_theme_switched()` function.

> Checks if a theme has been changed and runs `‘after_switch_theme’` hook on the next WP load

Note: The action has one argument, named `$old_theme` that you can access. After running the filter, the option `theme_switched` gets set to true.

Comment: well I am still not sure what to do with it exactly to get to my goal.